getInitialprops in next js is not working with app router
enter image description here
I have used App router in next js and i am unable to use getinitalprops in next js The function User.getInitialProps  is not even called what should be done to resolve it?
I tried using general axios method to fetch from the URL it works but i want getInitialprops to do this work
